# Display distortion after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, multiple-monitors, 18.04, display, kde

After upgrading Kubuntu to 18.04, I have the following problem: characters sometimes display with distortion: random color pixels surround black letters on white background (or vice versa).

The issue only affects a monitor connected via HDMI, the other display using regular VGA is not affected (I use a dual monitor setup).

The system now uses Wayland display manager, sddm and KDE.
No proprietary drivers (Driver manager does not suggest that they are needed).

Answer (score 0):

## The problem was caused by a monitor having been reset

Changing physical display settings in its menu eliminated character distortion. Problem is solved.

Possibly the monitor was reset during system upgrade.